# Vertx3.0 Simple Form upload

Tags: vert.x

Vertx3.0 http simpleform file uploader is throwing error for multiple file.

Am using vertx3.0 simple form upload. It is working fine when i upload single file. If the form has the input "multiple" and choose multiple files, The HTTPServerUpload is throwing error "Response has already been written". Since the response is end in the endhandler for 1st file, it is throwing this error for subsequent files. is there any other way for multiple files ?

Simpleform file upload using vertx3.0

```
public class SimpleFormUploadServer extends AbstractVerticle {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runner.runExample(SimpleFormUploadServer.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {
        vertx.createHttpServer()
                .requestHandler(req -> {
                    if (req.uri().equals("/")) {
                        // Serve the index page
                        req.response().sendFile("index.html");
                    } else if (req.uri().startsWith("/form")) {
                        req.setExpectMultipart(true);
                        req.uploadHandler(upload -> {
                            upload.exceptionHandler(cause -> {
                                req.response().setChunked(true)
                                        .end("Upload failed");
                            });

                            upload.endHandler(v -> {
                                req.response()
                                        .setChunked(true)
                                        .end("Successfully uploaded to "
                                                + upload.filename());
                            });
                            // FIXME - Potential security exploit! In a real
                            // system you must check this filename
                            // to make sure you're not saving to a place where
                            // you don't want!
                            // Or better still, just use Vert.x-Web which
                            // controls the upload area.
                            upload.streamToFileSystem(upload.filename());
                        });
                    } else {
                        req.response().setStatusCode(404);
                        req.response().end();
                    }
                }).listen(8080);

    }
}

Exception :

SEVERE: Unhandled exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Response has already been written
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpServerResponseImpl.checkWritten(HttpServerResponseImpl.java:561)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpServerResponseImpl.end0(HttpServerResponseImpl.java:389)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpServerResponseImpl.end(HttpServerResponseImpl.java:307)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpServerResponseImpl.end(HttpServerResponseImpl.java:292)
    at com.nokia.doas.vertx.http.upload.SimpleFormUploadServer$1$1$2.handle(SimpleFormUploadServer.java:85)
    at com.nokia.doas.vertx.http.upload.SimpleFormUploadServer$1$1$2.handle(SimpleFormUploadServer.java:1)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpServerFileUploadImpl.notifyEndHandler(HttpServerFileUploadImpl.java:213)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpServerFileUploadImpl.lambda$handleComplete$165(HttpServerFileUploadImpl.java:206)
    at io.vertx.core.file.impl.AsyncFileImpl.lambda$doClose$226(AsyncFileImpl.java:470)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$wrapTask$16(ContextImpl.java:335)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:358)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


index.html

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="/form" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" method="POST" name="wibble">
    choose a file to upload:<input type="file"  name="files" multiple="multiple"/><br>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [vertx-web](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/) to easily handle file uploads:

```
router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create());

router.post("/some/path/uploads").handler(routingContext -> {

    Set<FileUpload> uploads = routingContext.fileUploads();
    // Do something with uploads....
});
```

Moreover, you will take benefits of the [routing facility](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/#_routing_by_exact_path), and you can even [serve static files](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/#_serving_static_resources) such as index.html.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple file upload is achievable in `vert.x`. Use multiple upload button in HTML and use `uploadHandler` of `HttpRequest`. `UploadHandler` would be invoked as many times any many files have been uploaded.

```
    HttpServerRequest request = routingContext.request();
    request.setExpectMultipart(true);
    request.endHandler(new Handler<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(Void aVoid) {
            MultiMap entries = request.formAttributes();
            Set<String> names = entries.names();
            logger.info("UPLOAD_CONTENT: fileName = "+entries.get("fileName"));
            logger.info("UPLOAD_CONTENT: type = "+entries.get("type"));
            logger.info("UPLOAD_CONTENT: names = "+names);
            request.response().setChunked(true).end(createResponse("SUCCESS"));
        }
    });
    // This would be called multiple times
    request.uploadHandler(upload -> {

        upload.exceptionHandler(new Handler<Throwable>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(Throwable error) {
                logger.error("UPLOAD_CONTENT: Error while uploading content "+upload.filename());
                logger.error("UPLOAD_CONTENT: error = "+error.toString());
                error.printStackTrace();
                request.response().setChunked(true).end(createResponse("FAILURE"));
            }
        });
        upload.endHandler(new Handler<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(Void aVoid) {
                logger.info("UPLOAD_CONTENT: fileName = "+upload.filename());
                logger.info("UPLOAD_CONTENT: name = "+upload.name());
                logger.info("UPLOAD_CONTENT: contentType = "+upload.contentType());
                logger.info("UPLOAD_CONTENT: size = "+upload.size());
                UtilityFunctions.uploadToS3(upload.filename(), "testfolder");

            }
        });
        upload.streamToFileSystem(upload.filename());
    });
```